# Selecting a wrapping element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js

I'm doing some filtering in a pretty old web with jquery and nodejs, and I want to select the `b` elements that are wrapped by a `p`. I mean only those that are wrapped with a `p` without text.

**What I want to match**

```
<p><b>Some text</b></p>
```

**What I don't want to match**

```
<p>Some other text and some other elements <a>link</a><b>Some text</b> 
   and some more text of the parent p
</p>
```

Do you know any way I can select this first wrapped element and not the second? Is there any selector to select this?

Comment: `$('p b:empty')` try this

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gd8mdL72/

Comment: Thanks @guradio, but this is not what I want

Comment: I think i dont need to put that as an answer since you have accepted one already happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filter` method:

```
$('p > b').filter(function() {
   return $(this.parentNode) // get the p element
                .contents() // get all the child nodes
                .not(this) // exclude the current `b` element
                .length === 0; 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3v6w8a8y/

Comment: Yes! That's what I want

Answer (score 1):

Try using `:first-child` selector

```js
alert($(">b:first-child", "p").text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<p><b>Some text</b></p>
What I don't want to match

<p>Some other text and some other elements <a>link</a><b>Some text</b> 
   and some more text of the parent p
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. Are you looking like this?

**HTML**

```
 <p>Some other text and some other elements <a>link</a><b>Some text</b> 
    and some more text of the parent p</p>
 <p><b>Some text</b></p>
 <p>Some other text and some other elements <a>link</a><b>Some text</b>
```

and some more text of the parent p

**CSS**

```
 p b:first-child:nth-of-type(1)
 {
    font-size:30px;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ztms610a/)

Comment: What if the element you want it's not the second...?

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring()` to check if the first 3 letters of `html()` are equal to `<b>`.

```
$("p").each(function() {
   if ($(this).html().substring(0, 3) == "<b>") {
       // Do whatever
   }
});
```

As shown in this [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fv615bdb/).